# カスタムキーボードエクステンションからファイルが読み込めない

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var emoji = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
    var button11: UIButton!
    var button12: UIButton!
    var fFastBoot = true
    var fPri = CGFloat(20)
    var ifontSize = 18.0
    var RPath = ""

    // Portrait表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var portraitHeight: CGFloat = 190.0
    private var portraitWidth: CGFloat!

    // Landscape表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var landscapeHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    private var landscapeWidth: CGFloat!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

    }

    var realmPath: String {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let path = (paths[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm")
        return path
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pas = realmPath
        print(pas)

        // Perform custom UI setup here

        ・・・

        let inputText = "か"
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let results = realm.objects(dic)
            .filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText)
            .sorted("date", ascending: false)

        for result in results {
            print(result)
        }
    }
・・・
```

RealmのDBは以下のところになっている。これがまずいのか？

```
/Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/830BF1AF-9059-445F-AC17-FC40D97C9C6E/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/AF4996B9-848C-4BA9-BFBB-1B743A45431B/Documents/test.realm
```

実際は・・・

```
/Users/User/Desktop/ソフト開発/test/Documents/test.realm
```

ただ、iOSの場合、どちらも間違いになるのか？

わかる方、教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: 保存先のパスを`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)`としているので、そうなるのが当然です。シミュレータにインストールされたアプリケーションのドキュメントディレクトリです。`/Users/User/Desktop/ソフト開発/test/Documents/test.realm`はあなたのMacのディレクトリですので、そこにiPhoneのアプリケーションはアクセスできません。（例外的にシミュレータは同じマシンで動くのでアクセスできますが）。`/Users/User/Desktop/ソフト開発/test/Documents/test.realm`のファイルを利用する意味は、一時的にテストのために利用するくらいしかありませんが、何がしたいのですが？

Comment: まずこのテストでは、iOSのシュミレーターで`test.realm`の中のyomi「か」で始まるデータを読み込むことを目的としています。Realmのコードの動作検証です。ですので`print(result)`で複数のデータが出て来れば成功ですが、1つもデータが取り出せません。`test.realm`の中の「か」で始まるデータはリーダーで存在を確認しています。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あなたの確認している`test.realm`というのは`/Users/User/Desktop/ソフト開発/test/Documents/test.realm`ですよね？iPhoneアプリからMacのファイルが見られるというのはおかしいので、`realmPath`で取得しているファイルのほうにデータを入れるべきですよ。どうしても`/Users/User/Desktop/ソフト開発/test/Documents/‌​test.realm`のデータを使いたいというのであれば、シミュレータでしか動きませんが、`realmPath`で返しているパスを`return "/Users/User/De‌​sktop/ソフト開発/test/Documents/test.realm"`とすればいいです。あくまでもシミュレータでしか動きませんが。

Comment: `realmPath`の参照先パスが毎回変わってしまいます。辞書ファイルなどを実装する場合、どのようにするのが正しいのでしょうか？申し訳ありませんが、教えていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: アプリケーションを削除したり、異なるシミュレータで実行しているのでなければ、提示されているコードで毎回変わるということはありえません。毎回変わっているというのが、どのような結果からそう判断したのか教えてください。たとえば、変わってる部分はどこですか？

Comment: 上記コードに`print(pas)`と書いていて、今回のパスは`/Users/Junichi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/830BF1AF-9059-445F-AC17-FC40D97C9C6E/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/76C67AB4-5F82-450F-B3FA-EE2093DFAF9F/Documents/Dictionary.realm`となっています。この英数字の `76C67AB4-5F82-450F-B3FA-EE2093DFAF9F`の部分が質問時のものと違うのがわかっていただけると思います。取得後、ここに `test.realm `を放り込んでみるのですが、次の実行時にまた変わります。本当に申し訳御座いません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: データの取得ができないのは`2015-08-16 21:58:41.702 test-key[76427:4697300] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)`が、原因でしょうか？

Comment: それはデータが取得できないのとは関係ありません。原因はあなたが見ているファイルにはデータが入っていないことなのは間違いありません。

Comment: 「iOS（ストアアプリについてはOSXも）には、サンドボックスによるファイル読み込みの制約がある」という前提を共有してあげた方がいいような…。その上でどう実装するべきなのかは、[iOSアプリケーション プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf)やRealm Swiftなら[初期データとしてRealmをアプリケーションにバンドルする](https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/)を読むと良い気がします。

Comment: これの使い方がまだわかりませんが、`NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(_:toPath:error:)`で、コピーして使えという事でしょうか？（プロジェクト設定のBuild Phaseタブで、”Copy Bundle Resources”にRealmファイルを追加した上で）。 Realm Browserでデータが入っている事は確認しているので・・・。一応`/Users/User/Desktop/ソフト開発/test/Documents/‌​test.realm `の直指定でもデータ読めません。

Comment: あと、直接は関係ないですが、日本語のパスはいろいろと問題を引き起こすので使わないことをお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。表記を英語に変えてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エクステンションについての話であることを失念していました。

エクステンションの場合に決まったディレクトリにファイルを保存してそのデータを再利用できるようにするには、App Groupを設定して共有ディレクトリにファイルを配置する必要があります。

**参考URL**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

App Groupを設定するにはまず、デベロッパーサイトでApp GroupのIDを登録する必要があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そして、Xcodeのプロジェクト設定から、キーボードのターゲットを選択し、「Capabilities」タブにある「App Groups」をオンにします。

そして、先ほど追加したApp Group IDにチェックを入れます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そうするとApp Groupが利用できるようになっていますので、共有ディレクトリのパスは下記のコードで取得します。

```
var realmPath: String {
    let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.kishikawakatsumi.realm")
    let filePath = containerURL?.filePathURL?.path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm")

    return filePath!
}
```

引数のApp Group IDはご自分で作成したものに変更してください。

これで、毎回ファイルの保存先が変わってしまうことは無くなりますので、このファイルに初期データを保存して利用します。

Comment: なんとなくわかってきましたが、未だエラーに泣かされています。一応App GroupのID登録をして、「App Groups」をオンにして登録し、`containerURL `のパスを`print`コマンドで取得してDBをそこに放り込みました。
しかし、 `Initialization of immutable value 'filePath' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it `というものと、`stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use stringByAppendingPathComponent on NSString instead.` が `let filePath = containerURL?.filePathURL?.path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm") `に対して出てしまいます。
まいった・・・

Comment: それはまた違う文法の問題ですね。これまでの質問から考えて、アプリケーションを作るために必要な知識が不足していますので、一度文法やプログラミングの基本を勉強されるのがいいと思います。それはさておき、この問題についてはやはりコメントで回答するのは不可能ですので、必要なら新しく質問を作ってください。

Comment: プログラムの基本は、近いうちに勉強いたします。お騒がせして申し訳御座いません。
別途質問いたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。