# 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift

[カスタムキーボードエクステンションからファイルが読み込めない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14476/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A0%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%81%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
を参考にして，App GroupのID登録をして、「App Groups」をオンにして登録し、

```
containerURL
```

のパスをprintコマンドで取得してDBをそこに放り込みました。 しかし、

```
Initialization of immutable value 'filePath' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
```

というものと、

```
stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use stringByAppendingPathComponent on NSString instead.
```

が

```
let filePath = containerURL?.filePathURL?.path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm")
```

に対して出てしまいます。

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var emoji = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
    var button11: UIButton!
    var button12: UIButton!
    var fFastBoot = true
    var fPri = CGFloat(20)
    var ifontSize = 18.0
    var RPath = ""

    // Portrait表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var portraitHeight: CGFloat = 190.0
    private var portraitWidth: CGFloat!

    // Landscape表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var landscapeHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    private var landscapeWidth: CGFloat!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

    }

    var realmPath: String {
        let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.AppGroupKeybora")
        let filePath = containerURL?.filePathURL?.path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm")

        return filePath!
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pas = realmPath
        print(pas)

        // Perform custom UI setup here

        ・・・

        let inputText = "か"
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let results = realm.objects(dic)
            .filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText)
            .sorted("date", ascending: false)

        for result in results {
            print(result)
        }
    }
・・・
```

Comment: `let filePath = ...`の部分はどこにあるんですか？ご提示のコードにその部分がありませんが？

Comment: すみません。修正いたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージの通りで、

```
stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use stringByAppendingPathComponent on NSString instead.
```

`stringByAppendingPathComponent(_:)`は`NSString`のメソッドなので、`String`にはありません。
`stringByAppendingPathComponent(_:)`メソッドを使うには、オブジェクトを`NSString`にキャストする必要があります。

なのですが、`NSURL`にもパスを追加するメソッド`URLByAppendingPathComponent(_:)`があるので、それを使って、`NSURL`のままパスを組み立てて、最後にNSStringにするのがいいと思います。

```
var realmPath: String {
    let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.AppGroupKeybora")
    return containerURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm").path!
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし別途質問しましたが`let realm = try! Realm()`でエラーが出て、データが読み出せません・・・