# stringByAppendingPathComponentのエラーについて

Tags: swift

パスの設定をする際、エラーが生じてしまいます。これはどのように書き直すのがよろしいのでしょうか？教えてくださる方がいましたら、どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

質問文の更新ですが、getCacheDirectory()の返り値の型はNSStringです。

```
func getFileURL() -> NSURL{
    let path  = getCacheDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)//ここでエラーが出ます。

    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    return filePath
}
```

Comment: [StackOverFlow（日本語版） - 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14495/stringbyappendingpathcomponent-is-unavailable) この質問に対する回答が、そのまま参考にできると思います。ぜひご覧ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
以前そちらは拝見したのですが、エラーが残っているままです。

Comment: ということは、関数`getCacheDirectory()`の返り値の型は、`NSString`だということですか？この点は、質問文中に明記しておくべきだと思います。コメントを連ねないで、質問文の更新という形でお答え願います。

Answer (score 1):

> エラーのメッセージは、 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use
>   URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead. というものです。

でしたら、関数`getCacheDirectory()`の返値の型は、`String`だと思われます。
型（クラス名）を確認するには、`dynamicType`を使います。（以下の確認コードとその結果は、Xcode 7.0.1、Swift 2.0で実行したものです。旧バージョンだと、おなじ結果にならないかもしれません）

```
print(getCacheDirectory().dynamicType)
```

返値の型が`NSString`であれば、`__NSCFString`と出力するはずです。`__NSCFString`は、`NSString`のクラスクラスタのひとつです。
返値の型が`String`であれば、そのまま`String`と出力します。

Comment: お手数おかけして申し訳ありません。エラーのメッセージは、
'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead.
というものです。

Comment: 些事ですが、この手のメソッドの`NSString`は`NSCFString`ではなく`NSPathStore2`になる気がします（一応、XCode7.0.1 Swift2.0環境下で試してみましたが、この結果になりました）。

Comment: @quesera2 はい、自信がないので、「します。」じゃなくて「するはずです。」と言葉を濁してあります（苦）

Answer (score 1):

`getCacheDirectory()`の実装が分かりませんが、

```
func getCacheDirectory() -> NSString {
    return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).last!
}
```

のようなものであれば、普通に`stringByAppendingPathComponent`は使えます。

```
let path  = (getCacheDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

のようにキャストする方法もありますが、一度`NSURL`に変換する方法が好まれます。

---

Swiftは`String`と`NSString`の間に暗黙の変換がありますが、バージョンを経ることに段々と制約が増えていきます。

理由は、Swiftの`String`が値型であることに対して、Objective-Cの`NSString`は参照型であることかと思います。

`NSString`はクラスクラスタなので、複数のサブクラス実装がありますが、それらすべてに対してブリッジしてしまうので、`NSString`のサブクラス実装によってはコピー処理によって予期せぬパフォーマンス性能劣化を引き起こすからです。

Swift 1.2から2.0で、`stringByAppendingPathComponent`のようなパス文字列を扱うメソッド群（実装が`NSPathStore2`にあると考えられるもの）を使うと、

> 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead.

というコンパイルエラーが出るようになりました。これは上述の問題を回避するために一度`NSURL`に変換して、`URLByAppendingPathComponent`で代替するべきだというメッセージですので、それに従うのが無難かと思います。