# iOSでRealmデータベースを開こうとするとエラーになる(AppGroupの使用）

Tags: swift, ios8, realm

[カスタムキーボードエクステンションからファイルが読み込めない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14476/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A0%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%81%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
上記を参考にしていますが・・・

```
print(realmPath)
```

では

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/****-****--****/test.realm
```

となりますが・・・

```
let realm = try! Realm(path: realmPath)
```

のところで、

```
2015-10-16 08:58:46.720 Test-Keyboard[8880:557651] ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";}
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "open() failed: Operation not permitted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=open() failed: Operation not permitted, Error Code=1}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.59/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 50
(lldb)
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。

データベースファイルを共有エリアにコピーとかが必要なのか？
でも、それもgoogleで探していますが、方法がわかりません。

ソースは下記の通りです。

どうか改善策を、教えていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var emoji = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}



class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
    var button11: UIButton!
    var button12: UIButton!
    var fFastBoot = true
    var fPri = CGFloat(20)
    var ifontSize = 18.0
    var RPath = ""

    // Portrait表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var portraitHeight: CGFloat = 190.0
    private var portraitWidth: CGFloat!

    // Landscape表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var landscapeHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    private var landscapeWidth: CGFloat!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

    }


    var realmPath: String {
        let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.AppGrouptestKeybora")
        return containerURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm").path!
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Perform custom UI setup here

        ・・・

        let inputText = "か"
        print("test1")  
        print(realmPath)
        realm = try! Realm(path: realmPath)  //ここでエラー
        print("test1.5")
        let results = realm.objects(dic)
            .filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText)
            .sorted("date", ascending: false)
        print("test2")


        for result in results {
            print(result)
        }
        print("test3")
    }
・・・
```

こんなのも、関係あるでしょうか？

```
func createPath() -> String {

    let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory , NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let databaseStr = "test.realm"
    let dbPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingString(databaseStr)

    // BEGING MODIFICATION
    let fileMan = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if !(fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath)) {    // The database does not already exist in Documents directory
        if let source = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingString(databaseStr) {
            if !(fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(source)) {
                print("RealmDB - file \(databaseStr) not found in bundle")
            } else {
                do {
                    try fileMan.copyItemAtPath(source, toPath: dbPath)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("RealmDB - failed to copy writable version of DB!")
                    print("Error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // END MODIFICATION

    return dbPath
}
```

Comment: 前に質問された時はできてたんですよね？何か変えたところはありませんか？

Comment: 大きな違いは、swiftがベータから正式版に変わりました。

Comment: DBが、realmPathの差すところに無いのかもしれません・・・なんらかの方法でコピーが必要でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記にありますように、共有コンテナでファイルを読み書きするには、フルアクセスの許可が必要です。

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW3

まず、キーボードエクステンションのInfo.plistの`NSExtensionAttributes`の`RequestOpenAccess`を`YES`にします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そうすると、設定.appの自分のキーボードのところが先に進めるようになっているはずなので、「フルアクセスを許可」をオンにします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます。フリーズはしなくなりました。が、realmPath関数で開いたDBが存在しないか、空っぽのようです。つまりデータが取得できません。作成したRealmのデータファイルが共有エリアにいないようです。どうしたらいいのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 新しくRealmファイルを作っているのだから空なのは当然です。